# Extrusion of 2d building footprints according to heights using python

Tags: python, 3d, extrude

I have 2d building footprints as polygonz geometries and building heights as attribute. I want to extrude them according to height values and generate building surfaces and polyhedral building records.

For this purpose in python I copy vertices of footprint and increase z values of coordinates according to heights then add these new vertices to my vertice list. So finally I achieve 8 points that represents corners of block shaped building as you can see in the picture.

[image: Footprint extrusion]

How can I triangulate using these points and create triangles that represent surfaces of building using python?

Can I use a triangle library although it uses only 2d points as arguments?

Comment: Can you explain your use case, and where/how do you plan to use the resulting geometry? Building the triangles is easy, but depending on how you'll use them, the approach may vary.

Comment: I am trying to create 3d building models from 2d footprints. I want to create to list which stores data, faces (triangles list) and index list (which vertices belong to these triangles). Thus, I can write these geometries to files such as CİTYGML or ESRI multipatch shapefile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230994/creating-simple-citygml-3d-models-based-on-2d-shapefiles-alkis-shp2gml-using-p) as it contains sample code to create CityGML surfaces.

The relevant part for footprint extrusion is:

```
polygon = []
for point_A, point_B in zip(points_2D[:-1], points_2D[1:]):
    surface = []
    surface.append((point_A[0], point_A[1], roof_height))
    surface.append((point_B[0], point_B[1], roof_height))
    surface.append((point_B[0], point_B[1], ground_height))
    surface.append((point_A[0], point_A[1], ground_height))
    surface.append((point_A[0], point_A[1], roof_height))

    polygon.append(surface)
```

In this format, you can define surfaces (they do not need to be triangles) with a list of tuples defining the points (the tuples must be 3 dimensional as we are generating 3D structures here). Also, each surface needs to start and end on the same point (making it a closed 3D surface).

Remember that each surface points need to be declared in the same order,  in counterclockwise direction as seen from outside (this is how we specify which direction the "face" is pointing).

You'll also need to generate roofs and other polygons. The linked question shows how to do that too.